# Formatting Dates with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, string-to-datetime

I have a question in regards to formatting dates in a column in my dataframe.
I'm a bit confused as to why it isn't formatting as I was following the instructions as to how to use the `pd.to_datetime` method.

Would anyone be able to provide me any insight into how one would format a date such as '`1230768318`'  using Pandas?

Many thanks.

Comment: is '1230768318' a time stamp??

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael 
Its working now! I will go look up what the unit='s' did to get it to work.

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi time is stored as integer seconds/nanoseconds/milliseconds (depending on the system) from 1970/01/01.  1230768318 is integer seconds.  @ rachel-solomon , the unit='s' in this case indicates that this timestamp is integer seconds rather than milliseconds or nanoseconds.